# Pinching issues

Tags: topology

How do i model these 2 shapes (a sphere and a slightly flattened sphere) so that there are no corners visible? This image cant show the topology errors but trust me there is. 2 corners when subdivided gives such small bumps in 4 corners.
[image]

[image]

These are the corners that creat bumps after subdiv modifiers

Comment: You could give your sphere a Shrinkwrap modifier and use a UV Sphere as target?

Comment: @moonboots no but my object is to make the other slightly flattened shape also shrinkwrap thru uvsphere will have top n bottom pinching

Comment: Use UV Sphere, and position poles on the middles of the flattened areas. That is, flatten the UV Sphere vertically.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ok!